# foreach Freeze / Hangup

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I'm running R on a remote Linux server and having an issue where parallel code causes the program to freeze (no error message). I've posted some toy code that replicates the problem below. The same code runs fine (< 1 second) on my PC at home so I'm at a loss for how to debug.

Even if it's unclear what the problem is, any advice on debugging this would be really useful. Thanks!

```
# Prelims
library(stringdist)
library(doParallel)
rm(list = ls())
cat("\014")

# Start parallel
registerDoParallel(cores=2)

# Works
cat("Test #1","\n")
foreach (i=1:2, .packages="stringdist") %dopar% {
    cat(stringdist("JOHN","JAHN",method="jaccard",q=2),"\n")
}

# Works
cat("Test #2","\n")
foreach (i=1:2, .packages="stringdist") %do% {
    cat(stringdist("JOHN",c("JAHN","DJIN"),method="jaccard",q=2),"\n")
}

# Doesn't work -- spawns two workers and freezes
cat("Test #3","\n")
test<-foreach (i=1:2, .packages="stringdist") %dopar% {
    cat(i,"\n")
    stringdist("JOHN",c("JAHN","DJIN"),method="jaccard",q=2)
}

stopImplicitCluster()
```

Output / result:

[image]

Comment: I wonder how can you print when using parallel?

Comment: No idea -- that's above my paygrade in terms of the server's R setup. foreach does not print on my home PC.

Answer (score 0):

Only a partial solution, but looking more carefully I saw that "stringdist" already uses multiple threads. The "nested parallel" aspect of this seemed to be causing problems in the Linux server setup, albeit not always and not on my home PC [not sure why].

Setting "nthread=1" as a stringdist option allows me to use parallel foreach.